# Regex Pattern Matching: Using only the start and end of a pattern for matching

Tags: c#, regex, string, pattern-matching, string-matching

Hi I am really struggling with this problem;

I am trying to use regex to match the start and end of a pattern where the middle of the pattern can change. So I would like to use a regex expression that will match the start which is constant and the end which is constant can anyone help?

For instance the start of the pattern is "/>" and ends with "abc"

I am using c#.

Thanks

Comment: Provide a sample please.

Comment: ...and please describe in more detail what start/end can look like (letters, digits, punctuation...) and what kinds of text are allowed in-between. Also please specify whether you want to *find* such patterns in larger texts, or if you want to *match* a given string against the regex.

Comment: For instance the start of the pattern is "/>" and ends with "abc".....

Answer (score 4):

```
^abc(.*)xyz$
```

Would match everthing that starts with abc and ends with xyz.

Answer (score 2):

There are several options:

Lets say you have the text:

```
<foo/> hello first abc hello second abc <bar/> hello third abc
```

I will show three regexes, and what they will match:

```
/\/>.*abc/
```

will match:

```
/> hello first abc hello second abc <bar/> hello third abc
```

Instead of matching greedy, you can also take as little as possible:

```
/\/>.*?abc/
```

This will match

```
/> hello first abc
/> hello third abc
```

But maybe you want to match greedy, but not when a tag is opened in between, than you could do for instance:

```
 /\/>[^<]*abc/
```

This wil match

```
/> hello first abc hello second abc
/> hello third abc
```

If you specify more clearly what you want, I can specify my answer more clearly ;)

Comment: I was  trying to add a code comment but it is getting very messy. I have tired to implement what you have shown above but I cannot get it to work could you please have a look. string pattern = @"/\/>[^<]*abc/";

Comment: I notated in the defacto standard syntax, between slashes. Perl and tools like that do it that way. In C# it's just a string, and you don't need the leading and trailing slash, nor do you need to escape slashes, so it would become: string pattern = @"/>[^<]*abc";

Answer (score 1):

The key items you are looking for are ^ which matches the start of a line and $ which matches the end of a line.  You can use these in your pattern to check for specific characters at the start or end of your string.

Answer (score 0):

```
^\/\u003E.*?abc$.
```

This will match string starts with "/>" and ends with "abc" eg."/>xyzabc"